# InjectionResolver with Jersey 2.x -- Resource being called twice

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, hk2

I am attempting to figure out how to use a custom annotation and HK2 to inject something into a Resource method.  Because I'm in a Spring webapp environment, I just piled on the existing helloworld-spring-webapp Jersey 2 example.  My problem is, is the Resource method is called twice.  The first time, the injection happens successfully, the second time, it does not.

InjectionResolver.resolve() method

```
@Override
public Object resolve(Injectee injectee, ServiceHandle<?> root) {
    return "THIS HAS BEEN INJECTED APPROPRIATELY";
}
```

Binder.configure() method

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(SampleInjectionResolver.class).to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<SampleParam>>() {}).in(Singleton.class);
}
```

ResourceConfig registering of binder

```
public MyApplication () {
    register(new SampleInjectionResolver.Binder());
    ...
```

JerseyResource.getHello()

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getHello(@SampleParam String inject) {
    System.err.println("EXECUTING!");
    System.err.println("*******************************INJECTED: " + inject);
    return inject;
}
```

Server output from a **SINGLE** call

```
EXECUTING!
*******************************INJECTED: THIS HAS BEEN INJECTED APPROPRIATELY
EXECUTING!
*******************************INJECTED:
```

Have I missed a configuration somewhere?  I can't figure out why it's being called twice.  I'm assuming if I fix that, the issue of the InjectionResolver not working on the 2nd call will be a non-issue.

Answer (score 3):

I faced with the exactly same issue - Twice call of the annotated resource method.
After deep investigation, I have found the way, how to use custom annotation in the Jersey 2.x.

Custom annotation class (TestMessage.java):

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface TestMessage {}
```

Custom annotation resolver (TestMessageResolver.java):

```
public class TestMessageResolver {
    // InjectionResolver implementation
    public static class TestMessageInjectionResolver extends ParamInjectionResolver<TestMessage> {
        public TestMessageInjectionResolver() {
            super(TestMessageValueFactoryProvider.class);
        }
    }

    // ValueFactoryProvider implementation
    @Singleton
    public static class TestMessageValueFactoryProvider extends AbstractValueFactoryProvider {
        @Inject
        public TestMessageValueFactoryProvider(MultivaluedParameterExtractorProvider mpep, ServiceLocator injector) {
            super(mpep, injector, Parameter.Source.UNKNOWN);
        }

        @Override
        protected Factory<?> createValueFactory(Parameter parameter) {
            Class<?> classType = parameter.getRawType();

            if (classType == null || (!classType.equals(String.class))) {
                return null;
            }

            return new AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory<String>() {
                @Override
                public String provide() {
                    return "testString";
                }
            };
        }
    }

    // Binder implementation
    public static class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(TestMessageValueFactoryProvider.class).
                to(ValueFactoryProvider.class).
                in(Singleton.class);

            bind(TestMessageInjectionResolver.class).
                to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<TestMessage>>(){}).
                in(Singleton.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Custom annotation usage (JerseyResource.java):

```
@Path("jersey")
public class JerseyResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMethod(@TestMessage String message) {
        return "getMethod(), message=" + message;
    }
}
```

Resolver registration(SpringJerseyApplication.java):

```
public class SpringJerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public SpringJerseyApplication() {
        register(JerseyResource.class);
        register(new TestMessageResolver.Binder());
    }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful :)

Comment: What if the annotation had both PARAMETER and METHOD as target? How should that be handled?

Comment: @alexander-aleksiuk, were you able to identify the exact reason the method was being called twice? I have an implementation that is [very similar to yours](https://github.com/l0s/jersey-hmac-auth/tree/283cfb401bf6893c77a694036e993d0f903e0e20/server2/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/auth/hmac/server), but the resource method is still called twice. The difference, however, is that the first time, the parameter is not injected and the second time, it is.

Comment: Nevermind, my issue turned out to be unrelated. A more detailed explanation is available on [JIRA](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2167) and I implemented a [fix](https://github.com/l0s/jersey-hmac-auth/commit/e0cf11bd2d9fa8bca3f97126f003d812616c7084).